# ¿Cómo inicializo una variable en la que mi página entra varias veces?

Tags: php

En mi página web tengo un script en donde se entra varias veces, como `PHP` siempre lo inicia desde 0, siempre me hace el mismo bucle o sea, así:

```
$contador = -1;
if ($contador == -1 )
{
    $contador++;
    $contador2=$contador;
    $_SESSION['contador'] =$contador2;
    $_SESSION['contador'] ++;
    if ($_SESSION['contador'] >= 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['contador'] ++;
    }
}
```

Y el resultado que me muestra siempre es 2 porque cada vez que entro se inicializa en -1, ¿cómo evito esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si siempre igualas la variable de sesión $_SESSION['contador'] al valor de una variable establecida para cada ejecución, nunca vas a conservar los cambios que se hagan. Inicializa la sesión con session_start y asigna un nuevo valor a $_SESSION['contador']

```
<?php

session_start();

// Si no se ha establecido la variable, o su valor es nulo:
if (!isset($_SESSION['contador']) || $_SESSION['contador'] === null) {
    $_SESSION['contador'] = -1;
}

if ($_SESSION['contador'] == -1 ) {
    // Primera vez que entra al bucle... Haz lo que sea necesario.
} else {
    // Segunda y sucesivos accesos al script... Haz lo que sea necesario.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente quieres esto. La primera vez inizializas la variable, el resto le sumas uno:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['contador'])) {
    $_SESSION['contador'] = 1; //Doy el primer valor al contador
}else{
    $_SESSION['contador']++; //Incrementa en 1 el contador
}
```